# How can I write a function to find missing number in PHP

Tags: php

I am a newbie in PHP. I have been given the following as homework:
Write a php function called findMissing that receives 3 parameters. The function must
determine and return a missing number in an array of numbers – note: only one number will
be missing from the series of numbers, the number you must find. All the numbers will be
integers.
◦ $start : This will be an integer indicating the minimum number the array can contain.
◦ $end : This will be an integer indicating the maximum number the array can contain.
◦ $numbers : An array with numbers between $start and $end. This array might not
be sorted. There is no guarantee that the first or last number in the array will correspond
to $start and $end respectively. $start and $end are inclusive in the range of
numbers
As an example: findMissing(1, 5, array(2,5,1,3)); must return 4 as the
missing number. The array $numbers will always contain $end - $start number of
elements.

So far I have the following code:

```
 function findMissing($start,$end,$numbers)
        {
            if ($start >0 && $end >0){

                for ($x=0; $x<=end; $x++) {
                  $numbers=array($x);         
             } 
               }    
            foreach ($numbers as $value){

                echo $value;
            }
        }
```

Please help because I am stuck

Comment: You only need a FOR loop with in_array() function
It's just 3 lines of code...

Comment: `$start >0 && $end >0` - explanation please. why did you write this?

Comment: can you explain in *words* (without code) how you would solve such a task?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may try this

```
<?php

$start      = 1;
$end        = 5;
$numbers    = array(2,5,1,3);

findMissing($start,$end,$numbers);

function findMissing($start,$end,$numbers)
{
    $range[$start-1] = 0;   // here, it will be $range[0] = 0;
    for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++)
    {
        $range[$i] = $range[$i-1]+1;
        if(!in_array($range[$i], $numbers))
        {
            echo '<br> Missing no= '. $i;
            //return $i;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Hope this will be helpful...

Comment: incorrect. the code assumes that `$start` is `1` (and the code is also needlessly complicated)

Comment: Yes the $start is 1, as it can be anything in the function call. (the simplest solution)

Comment: *sigh*. your function doesn't work if start is not 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you are faced with a problem, and this is not just for programming, first thing first is you have to picture the solution in your head and see it working.

Given this task a few ideas come to mind:

You can sort the array and loop through it, as soon as a number that's not equal to the previous number + 1 occurs, you can safely say that `previous number + 1` is your missing number.

Another way you can solve this is by looping in the range of `$start` to `$end` and check if each value is in the given array with `in_array()`. As soon as you encounter a value that's not, needless to say, this is your number.

If your goal isn't to learn, but to just get rid of that homework, drop a comment I'll scribble the function for you.

Comment: "If your goal isn't to learn, but to just get rid of that homework, drop a comment I'll scribble the function for you." - WTF?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what ?

Answer (score 0):

dude!! here is a simple solution for that
            add all numbers between $start and $end as $sumAll
            and also add all the elements of that array as $sum
            now $missingNumber = $sumAll-$sum !!
Do it it would be fun :)